# Determine the values of $a$ and $b$, for which all solutions become bounded when $t\geq 0$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Let $a$ and $b$ are real numbers, \begin{align} \begin{cases} x' = 2y - 4x + a\\\\ y' = 3x + y + b \end{cases} \end{align}
>
> Determine the values of $a$ and $b$, for which all solutions become
> bounded when $t\geq 0$. $(x=x(t), y=y(t))$

My solution;

Firstly I found eigenvalues and eigenvector.

$\lambda_1=2, \lambda_2=-5$

and the corresponding eigenvectors are

$v_1=\left [ \begin{matrix}
    1 \\
    3 \\
   \end{matrix} \right ]$,
$v_2=\left [ \begin{matrix}
    -2 \\
    1 \\
   \end{matrix} \right ]$.

So, solution of homogeneous part is

$x_h=c_1e^{2t}$$\left [ \begin{matrix}
    1 \\
    3 \\
   \end{matrix} \right ]+c_2e^{-5t}\left [ \begin{matrix}
    -2 \\
    1 \\
   \end{matrix} \right ].$

and I found particular solutions like this

$x_p=\left [ \begin{matrix}
    \frac {a-2b}{10} \\
    \frac {-3a-4b}{10} \\
   \end{matrix} \right ]$

Consequently, general solution is

$x_g=c_1e^{2t}\left [ \begin{matrix}
    1 \\
    3 \\
   \end{matrix} \right ]+c_2e^{-5t}$$\left [ \begin{matrix}
    -2 \\
    1
   \end{matrix} \right ]+\left [ \begin{matrix} \frac {a-2b}{10} \\\frac {-3a-4b}{10}
   \end{matrix} \right ]
$

$e^{-5t}$ part goes to $0,$ as $t$ goes infinity and $e^{2t}$ part blows up as $t$ goes infinity. But I can't found $a$ and $b$. I'm stuck. I would be very appreciate if someone could help.

Comment: @Moo maybe coefficients are different but I'm sure about non-homogeneous part.

Comment: @Moo This is an old exam question. I remember that when I solved it in the exam, I found one positive and one negative eigenvalue. and since the inhomogeneous part is a constant number, I think the particular solution will be similar. am I wrong? maybe i think ridiculous but i'm still a student so apologies for that. Can you give me an example question where I can find the real numbers a and b?

Comment: @Moo unfortunately no but I have matlab if it works.

Comment: @Moo analyze for determine a and b?

Comment: @Moo  I will try your suggestion soon but so do you think they might have expected an answer like this? "Because of eigenvalue of 2, this solution will blows up. The a and b values do not affect the result."